# 301 redirects in .htaccess forming incorrect redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect http://brisbaneamazingrace.com.au/details.html to http://www.teambonding.com.au/activities/amazing-race-brisbane which is a different domain.  In my .htaccess file I have

```
Redirect 301 http://brisbaneamazingrace.com.au/details.html http://www.teambonding.com.au/activities/amazing-race-brisbane
```

But the redirect goes to http://teambonding.com.au/activities/amazing-race-brisbane**details.html**

It keeps adding the details.html to the end of the redirect url.  Whats up with that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RedirectMatch` for regex matching:

```
RedirectMatxh 301 ^/details\.html$ http://www.teambonding.com.au/activities/amazing-race-brisbane
```

Also test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: i never used Redirect, maybe you know - Why it adds filename ?

Comment: `Redirect` does add current path as trailing path in target that's why I suggested you to use `RedirectMatch` after clearing your browser cache.